# hangfire convert parameter to json(Serialize)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, hangfire

When I login, the program creates an instance of InstaSharper (named :`IInstaApi`) that contains `httpclient`, `httpclienthandeler`, ...

And when I use this

```
  AddFollower adf = new AddFollower();
  RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("addfollow", () => adf.AddFollowerState(2,IInstaApi), "*/10 * * * *", TimeZoneInfo.Local, "default");
```

Hangfire when it sends those values TO create job, hangfire Serializes them (destroy my object and its not my object any more after DeSerialize ) 
what should I do so that my method that is used in Hangfire only has 2 parameter one **int** and one **InstaApi**?

what should I do? In the document it says I should use IOC but I don't know how I can use that

Comment: httoclient ?... not httpClient ?

Comment: Why is this tagged with autofac and ninject?  Please don't spam tags.

Comment: because it could be solve with  autofac and ninject (ioc)

Comment: You would only use one *or* the other.  Not both.  Tag your question appropriately.  It is not clear, at all, how either library is related to this question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your recurring job statically available and absolutely context-independent.
Just create a static method which will contain the whole logic and do all the job:

```
  public class AddFollowerJob
  {
      public static void Run() 
      { 
          AddFollower adf = new AddFollower();
          // do whatever you want here with adf
          // initialize API here
          adf.AddFollowerState(2, IInstaApi); 
          // handle results here
      }
  }

  RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("addfollow", () => AddFollowerJob.Run(), "*/10 * * * *", TimeZoneInfo.Local, "default");
```

The main idea is that Hangfire serializes your method call Expression into database and it must be context-independent, so that any server (even remote) can run this code.

It is a good idea to use IoC containers to not store these dependencies right in code, but it is not necessary. Just make sure that a method you pass to Hangfire is self-sufficient and independent.

Comment: and how can i send those parameters to run() method?

Comment: @ShoppingCenterCNC You don't need to. Initialize these parameters inside your `Run` method.

Comment: no,it should be sent by the job i cant do that.i think i should change the hangfire code that dont serialize the parameter value anymore

Comment: @ShoppingCenterCNC Why so? Could you show the usage case.

Comment: 2 is an id ; i wrote 2 for example